# Bootstrap Carousel does not auto-slide when routing back in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, bootstrap-4, carousel

The Problem is when I start my angular application the image slider using bootstrap carousel is working fine. But when I routing to the other view and coming back to the image slider view it's not auto sliding and also I can use next and prev button to change the images but it is not auto-sliding. It works only when I reload the page. How to solve this ?

**Here is my code**

**.html file**

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-pause="false">
    
      <!-- CAROUSEL INDICATORS -->
      <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <div *ngFor="let image of images;index as i;first as isFirst" [class.active]="isFirst">
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" [attr.data-bs-slide-to]="i" aria-current="true">
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <!-- CAROUSEL IMAGES -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="2000" *ngFor="let image of images;first as isFirst" [class.active]="isFirst">
          <img id="carouselImage" src="{{image}}" class="d-block w-100" height="707vh" alt="">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h3>It Differentiates Your Brand From Others</h3>
            <p>Kajah Industrial is The leading Industrial In The Country.</p>
            <button class="btn" (click)="btnService()">Watch Our Services</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <!-- NEXT AND PREV BUTTON -->
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel"  data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel"  data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
```

**.ts file**

```
import { bootstrap } from 'bootstrap';
...
 ngOnInit() {
    var myCarousel = document.querySelector('#myCarousel')
    var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarousel)
  }
```

**angular.json file**

```
 "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "./node_modules/aos/dist/aos.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
 "scripts": ["./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
             "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
             "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
             "./node_modules/aos/dist/aos.js"
            ]
```

**And also I found this error in the console**

*ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Carousel' of undefined at HomeComponent.ngOnInit *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things to consider. You can add `declare var $: any;` under the `import` statements in your `.ts` file. This will allow you to access `jQuery` in Angular which is used by bootstrap carousel.

You shouldn't try and initialize the carousel in the `ngOnInit` method, but instead use `ngAfterContentInit`. `ngOnInit` fires before the view renders, so your query selector can't find the component because Angular has not added it yet to the DOM.

You can [read here about Angular lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence).

**ngAfterContentInit**

> Respond after Angular projects external content into the component's view, or into the view that a directive is in.

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
  const myCarousel = document.querySelector('#myCarousel');
  const carousel = $(myCarousel).carousel();
}
```

Also you should use a `ViewChild` to reference the control instead of using `document.querySelector` as this Angular's preferred way of access DOM elements.

```
declare var $: any;

ViewChild('carousel', { static: false }) private _carousel: ElementRef;

ngAfterContentInit() {
   const myCarousel = this._carousel.nativeElement;
   const carousel = $(myCarousel).carousel();
}
```

In your html add `#carousel`

```
<div #carousel id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade"
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this bug with define a hidden control element:

```
 <div class="invisible">
    <ol>
      <li #carousel data-target="#slider" data-slide="next"></li>
    </ol>
 </div>
```

In above code data-target refer to id of bootstrap carosel component:

```
<div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 
</div>
```

Use ViewChild to access #carousel template variable:

```
 @ViewChild('carousel') carousel: ElementRef;
```

At ngAfterViewInit call to click on control element:

```
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.carousel.nativeElement.click();
    }, 5000)
  }
```